# How can I force QT Creator's toggle comment feature to not skip lines

Tags: c++, ide, qt-creator

Using QT Creator, given the following:

```
int example = 1;

if (example == 1)
{
  example = 2;
}
```

If I select that text and enter `ctrl-/` to toggle comments on the selection, I get:

```
//int example = 1;

//if (example == 1)
//{
//  example = 2;
//}
```

But I want to get:

```
//int example = 1;
//
//if (example == 1)
//{
//  example = 2;
//}
```

(The empty line is also commented out).

Does anyone know how to configure QT Creator to not skip empty lines when toggling comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is to use multi-line edition. If you have never used this feature, here are the instructions on QtCreator:

*Keyboard-only:* Put your cursor at the beginning of the first line you want to comment, press Shift+Alt, use the Down arrow to reach the last line, release Shift+Alt, type '//'.

*Keyboard + Mouse:* Select the code you want to comment and press Atl before releasing the left button of the mouse. Release Alt, and type '//'.

**Note:** It seems that QtCreator >= 3.2 is required to have a functional multi-line edition.

Comment: The Keyboard + Mouse version was a little trickier to get working.  You have to drag in a straight column.